# Django Query Writing for performance

Tags: python, django

I've a website with a lot of queries, it are taking +160 queries, so I know that I'm doing something wrong. Reading about queries I found something on my code that it's not a good pratice

```
def home(request):
    ads_all             = Advertising.actives().annotate(likes=Count('ad_likes')).order_by('-likes', '-published_dt') # All Ads selected
    ads_gold            = ads_all.all()[0:2] # Buy & Sell Home Page - Big ads
    ads_normal          = ads_all.all()[2:6] # Buy & Sell Home Page - Small ads
```

But I don't know how can I make this same thing in a good performance way. How can I do that?

Comment: here you have just two queries. The 160 should come from somewhere else. Also you can save one of these queries by writing:
top10 = ads_all.all()[0:6]
ads_gold = top10[0:2]
ads_normal = top10[2:6]
Maybe the big number of queries are coming from the template, where you render the objects. Do you use FK relationships during the rendering? Select_related or prefetch_related might help.

Comment: you can install django debug toolbar for analyzing the queries being generated, evaluation time, etc..

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'm using debug toolbar. If I use top10 = ads_all.all()[0:6] ads_gold = top10[0:2] ads_normal = top10[2:6] it will be just 1 query or 3?

Comment: @MaxFerreira By default, a QuerySet is "lazy" meaning that you haven't actually retrieved records from the database yet. The query is *run* as soon as you do something that requires records... such as slicing the results, as you do in the last two lines. There's nothing wrong with slicing results, but if you intend to further refine these results, it will be worth considering if you can accomplish the same goal with a QuerySet. IMO, there's no ideal number of queries, it's more a matter of whether your system is designed to support expected/observed usage in a responsive way.

Comment: In this case I'm sure that a lot of queries are making my system slowly. So, that's why I'm looking for a 'correct' way to slice these results better.